# mongodb count value of one field based on other

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named genre_collection of following structure :

```
user     | genres
 ----------------
 1       |   comedy
 1       |   action
 1       |   thriller
 1       |   comedy
 1       |   action
 2       |   war
 2       |   adventure
 2       |   war
 2       |   thriller
```

I'm trying to find the count for each genre for each user i.e. my ideal final result would be something like this :

```
1 | comedy |2
1 | action |1
1 | thriller |1
2 | war |2
2 | adventure |1
2 | thriller |1
```

Any helps would be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with aggregation using $group

try this :

```
db.genre_collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         _id:{
            genre:"$genres",
            user:"$user"
         },
         count:{
            $sum:1
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : { "genre" : "adventure", "user" : 2 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "genre" : "action", "user" : 1 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "genre" : "thriller", "user" : 2 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "genre" : "war", "user" : 2 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "genre" : "comedy", "user" : 1 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "genre" : "thriller", "user" : 1 }, "count" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
db.genre_collection.aggregate([
       {"$group" : {_id:{genres:"$genres"}, count:{$sum:1}}} ])
    ])
```

Hope it helps !!!